# Feature class not visible in geodatabase after running Alter Field in ModelBuilder

Tags: modelbuilder, fields-attributes, arccatalog

I'm using ModelBuilder in ArcGIS Desktop 10.5.1.

I have a simple model that clips and exports three feature classes, each to their own file geodatabase (`law`, `fire`, and `ems`). The model branches for the `fire` and `ems` feature classes both end by using the "Alter Field" to change the name of the field. The `law` feature class does not require this field name change. The model executes without any errors, warnings, or other messages. But, when I look at the two geodatabases for `fire` and `ems`, they appear to be empty (in ArcCatalog). The strange thing is, if I browse into the geodatabases in Windows Explorer, I can see all the of the system tables and I can confirm that they contain the feature classes (by name) that the model created. To pinpoint the issue, I re-ran the same model, but *without* the last step (Alter Field), and the feature class appears in the geodatabase as-expected.

Below is a clip of a branch of the model:

[image]

Below is a clip of the two geodatabases appearing to be empty, even after numerous refreshes within ArcCatalog (I even tried closing an re-launching all ArcGIS sessions):

[image]

And below is a view of the apparently empty geodatabases viewed through Windows Explorer, and a system table open in Notepad showing the feature class name highlighted (`emsFC`):

[image]